# Angular to flatten or massage Array

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a JSON response with arrays of arrays of object. I would like to know in angular way how to flatten it to display in Material Table.
I would like to flatten the accessID and desc into a flat array such as [ADPRATE, QUOCON, USRIDMAN].

```
"data": [
    [
        {
            "categoryId": "ADPDSHB",
            "categoryDesc": "Dashboard - Admin",
            "categoryAccess": [
                {
                    "BoRefAccess": {
                        "accessId": "ADPRATE",
                        "accessDesc": "Adoption Rate"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "BoRefAccess": {
                        "accessId": "QUOCON",
                        "accessDesc": "Quotation Conversion "
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "categoryId": "USRMAN",
            "categoryDesc": "User Management",
            "categoryAccess": [
                {
                    "BoRefAccess": {
                        "accessId": "USRIDMAN",
                        "accessDesc": "User ID Management"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

New Expected outcome, by flattening the inner array

```
  {
       {
        "categoryId": "ADPDSHB",
        "categoryDesc": "Dashboard - Admin",
        "categoryAccess": 
            {
                "BoRefAccess": {
                    "accessId": "ADPRATE",
                    "accessDesc": "Adoption Rate"
                }
            },
         },
            {
        "categoryId": "ADPDSHB",
        "categoryDesc": "Dashboard - Admin",
        "categoryAccess": 
            {
                "BoRefAccess": {
                    "accessId": "QUOCON",
                    "accessDesc": "Quotation Conversion"
                }
            },
         },
```

example of table

[image]

Comment: your expected outcomes syntax is wrong. surrounding {} should be changed to  []

Comment: ah yes...thanks for correcting... also if there anyway you can group all the access under their own category ?

Comment: Please look on my updated answr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try like this.

```
const data = {"data": [
    [
        {
            "categoryId": "ADPDSHB",
            "categoryDesc": "Dashboard - Admin",
            "categoryAccess": [
                {
                    "BoRefAccess": {
                        "accessId": "ADPRATE",
                        "accessDesc": "Adoption Rate"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "BoRefAccess": {
                        "accessId": "QUOCON",
                        "accessDesc": "Quotation Conversion "
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "categoryId": "USRMAN",
            "categoryDesc": "User Management",
            "categoryAccess": [
                {
                    "BoRefAccess": {
                        "accessId": "USRIDMAN",
                        "accessDesc": "User ID Management"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
]}
```

**Edit** : based on comment

```
data.data.map(item => {
    console.log(item[0])
    return {
       "categoryId" : item[0].categoryId,
       "categoryDesc" : item[0].categoryDesc, 
       "categoryAccess" : item[0].categoryAccess.filter(access =>access["BoRefAccess"].accessId === item[0].categoryId) 
    }
})
```

this logic filter out the category access array .it will display only item having samme category id. hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: i not sure why but I cant bring out flat function on my typescript environment

Comment: i have added another solution to answer using map function. please try that

Comment: to use flat method. you might need to add its polyfills in the polyfil.ts file.

Comment: thanks again, i updated the question with newer expected outcome

Comment: wow..this is something i have seen the best answer....i got the structure...
now the question is...how to display them into material table which column are accessID, accessDesc and its own categoryID?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/dgxaavxgpan?file=src%2Findex.html here is a link to stackblitz demo for material table. if you are facing any issue to implement. please let me know

Comment: yeap i know the way to implement the material table..but you see now the current data structure there are still nexted array within the objects...how to loop them out into the material table?

Answer (score 0):

You could do some custom for looping if you knew it was based on these specefic properties.

```
 let newDataObject;
 const idArray = [];
 const descArray = []
       data.forEach(objectArray => {
             objectArray.forEach(object => {
                 object.categoryAccess.forEach(category => {
                     idArray.push(category.BoRefAccess.accessId);
                     descArray.push(category.BoRefAccess.accessDesk);
                 }
             }
       }
// at this point you will have added in all of the elements into their respective arrays for all
// of the objects. You may have to alter your loop nesting, but that's the idea
```

Hope this helps,
Happy coding!

Comment: thanks again, i updated the question with newer expected outcome